# I have problem connecting wireless network in ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Aspire E5-574G Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac)

Tags: drivers, acer, atheros

I am unable to connect using wireless network (My wifi adapter is Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac). My laptop is Acer Aspire E5-574G. I have ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

> /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/

[These are the files in respective driver folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj2b9.png)

[Could not fetch firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2MEr.png)

Any suggestions to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue using this link

https://github.com/ajaybhatia/Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux